# Update dbus on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, dbus, bluez

I need to update DBus on my Raspberry Pi, in order to upgrade to the latest Bluez version (and I hope for performance benefits).  I can't use a package install, as the latest packaged version is old, so I "configure/make/make install".

The problem with this is that it appears to install alongside the old version, but in a different directory.  So, if I run `dbus-daemon --version`, I see the old version number following the install.

The original version (and launch path) is */usr/bin*, whereas my install is going to */usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin*.  I did try editing the path for launch in */lib/systemd/system/dbus.service*, but after this, Linux failed to start.

So now I have two versions of dbus on my Pi, with the old one booting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to successfully have D-Bus 1.10.18 on my Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie Lite Fresh (release 2017-04-10) :

[I use aptitude instead of apt-get. You can substitute one by another.]

```
sudo aptitude install -y libapparmor1
cd ~
wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.10.18-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg --auto-deconfigure -i libdbus-1-3_1.10.18-1_armhf.deb
wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dbus/dbus_1.10.18-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i dbus_1.10.18-1_armhf.deb
sudo reboot
```

and after reboot :

```
pi@RasPi3-Tests:~ $ dpkg -l dbus
Souhait=inconnU/Installé/suppRimé/Purgé/H=à garder
| État=Non/Installé/fichier-Config/dépaqUeté/échec-conFig/H=semi-installé/W=attend-traitement-déclenchements
|/ Err?=(aucune)/besoin Réinstallation (État,Err: majuscule=mauvais)
||/ Nom                     Version          Architecture     Description
+++-=======================-================-================-===================================================
ii  dbus                    1.10.18-1        armhf            simple interprocess messaging system (daemon and ...
```

and :

```
pi@RasPi3-Tests:~ $ dbus-daemon --version
D-Bus Message Bus Daemon 1.10.18
Copyright (C) 2002, 2003 Red Hat, Inc., CodeFactory AB, and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, share the failure log from "`journalctl -xe`" or "`systemctl status dbus`". Following might solve your problem,

- Make sure to stop the dbus before update it. "`systemctl stop dbus`"
- `systemctl daemon-reload` (Needs to run after changing service file of any daemon)
- Start dbus again, `systemctl start dbus`.
- check the binary path available in "echo $PATH", if not, export it. In your case, `export PATH=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH` should help

Note: Many applications will stop working when you stop dbus.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - I tried all but it's still loading the old daemon. systemctl status dbus gives the following output: dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-03-30 05:51:38 UTC; 6min ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Main PID: 434 (dbus-daemon)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
           └─434 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --...

Comment: If I run "dbus-daemon --version" I see the old version, 1.8.22, however if I run "/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/./dbus-daemon --version" I see the newly installed version, 1.10.16

Comment: From the status I can see that the dbus is started and running fine with /usr/bin path. Update the path to /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin in dbus.service file and restart the daemon. Make sure to reload the daemon. If the dbus failed to start, then share the "systemctl status dbus" output.

Comment: You can also use "ps -ef | grep dbus" to check from which path the dbus daemon started is the dbus is in running state.

Comment: I also tried configure with "./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc" which installs the new version over the existing dbus, but now the error when executing the dbus command is "dbus-daemon: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by dbus-daemon)
dbus-daemon: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by dbus-daemon)
dbus-daemon: relocation error: dbus-daemon: symbol _dbus_no_memory_message, version LIBDBUS_PRIVATE_1.10.16 not defined in file libdbus-1.so.3 with link time reference".

Comment: Is it possible that this upgrade simply isn't supported? I did find that it's possible to install the updated Bluez after installing the update DBus (with the default install location), even though the old DBus daemon is the one running.  Not ideal.... but it seems to work.

Comment: Yes. You can run multiple instance of dbus daemon, but not at most one for session bus and one for system bus. Try to upgrade the dbus or compile it from source and try compiling the bluez again. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install  python3-dbus